# Verwendung des Wortes »scharf« im Zusammenhang mit stark gewürztem Essen

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Kann man das Wort *scharf* verwenden, um auszudrücken, dass ein Essen stark gewürzt ist, ohne dass es im Sinne von *pfefferscharf* scharf ist? Synonyme, an die ich denke, sind, ohne mir ganz sicher zu sein: *streng gewürzt* und *stark gewürzt.*

Beispiel:

> Die Suppe ist scharf gewürzt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn ich Sie richtig verstanden habe, geht es Ihnen um den Unterschied zwischen

- Schärfe im Sinne von Pfefferschärfe (laut Wikipedia auch [geschmackliche Schärfe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschmackliche_Sch%C3%A4rfe) genannt), wie sie etwa durch Capsaicin oder Piperin hervorgerufen wird und
- Schärfe im Sinne von starker, wie auch immer gearteter Würzung.

Verwenden dürfen Sie natürlich beides – niemand wird es Ihnen verbieten. Die Frage ist nur, ob Sie nicht missverstanden werden, wenn Sie beispielsweise schreiben

> Der Kuchen ist ganz schön scharf.

Als Leser käme ich niemals auf die Idee, dass Sie damit Folgendes ausdrücken wollten:

> Der Kuchen ist sehr stark gesüßt.

Stattdessen würde ich denken, es handelte sich um Kuchen mit Chili- oder Ingwergeschmack. Hier verfehlt die Sprache ihren Zweck, dem Leser auf eindeutige Weise den gewünschten Inhalt mitzuteilen. So etwas ist erlaubt, aber schlechter Stil.

Comment: Und wieder einmal bitte ich um die Begründung, weshalb die Antwort abgewertet wurde! (@v... ?)

Comment: Ich finde das Beispiel "stark gesüßt" irreführend und schlecht, da Zucker kein Würzmittel ist. Ein stark gesüßter Kuchen wäre auch niemals "stark gewürzt"

Comment: @Iris, von Zucker habe ich gar nichts geschrieben. Dennoch kann es süße getrocknete Pflanzenteile geben, also Gewürze nach der Definition https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gew%C3%BCrz#Klassifizierung_nach_Herkunft.

Comment: In der Theorie mag Zucker als pflanzlicher Süßstoff als Gewürzmittel gelten, aber das sagt doch so niemand, oder? Würdest du zu einem Kuchen sagen, er sei stark gewürzt, wenn du sagen willst, dass er sehr süß sei. Ich bleibe dabei, diese Antwort ist für mich irreführend, daher -1.

Comment: Na eben nicht, das ist doch der Inhalt meiner Antwort. Aber schön erstmal -1 geben, obwohl man es nicht verstanden hat. Danke.

Comment: Die Frage dreht sich aber um die Frage, ob scharf ausdrückt ob Essen stark gewürzt ist und da geht dein Kuchenbeispiel total vorbei.

Comment: So so. Dann hat sich der OP beim grünen Haken wohl verklickt.

Answer (score 3):

"Stark/intensiv gewürzt" kann man verwenden. "Streng gewürzt" dagegen klingt negativ, "ein streng gewürztes Essen" würde ich sicher nicht mehr probieren wollen.

Es geht auch "würzig" oder "aromatisch", wobei beides sich auch auf einen starken Eigengeschmack oder -geruch beziehen kann ohne Gewürze zu verwenden.

Das Adjektiv meiner Wahl wäre "pikant". Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pikant) definiert pikant als "angenehm scharf durch verschiedene, fein aufeinander abgestimmte Gewürze [und Wein, Essig o. Ä.]"

Comment: *pikant* ist eine gute Wahl, falls es letztendlich mit *spice* verwandt sein sollte, wohl aber weniger, insofern mit *gespickt*, *Speck* vergleichbar, das seinerseits eher ... wie auch immer, synonym mit *deftig* ist es nicht, sondern nunmehr wohl eben so zu verstehen, wie du schon sagtest.

Comment: Vielleicht nimmst Du noch "aromatisch" mit auf, dann erspare ich mir eine Antwort, die Deine weitgehend wiederholt.

Comment: @ vectory, ich hab keine Ahnung was du meinst. Pikant und Speck haben nichts gemein. Pikant kommt von französisch piquant → fr eigentlich "stechend, spitz, stachelig" (https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/pikant)

Answer (score 2):

Man kann "scharf" für gut gewürzte Speisen verwenden, jedoch würde ich das als veraltet, ggf regional und heutzutage als verwirrend bezeichnen. Meiner Erfahrung nach verstehen die meisten Leute unter "scharfe Würzung" ausschließlich Würzungen im Sinne [des Wikipedia-Artikels zur "geschmacklichen Schärfe"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschmackliche_Sch%C3%A4rfe), also Pfeffer, Chili, Senf, Ingwer etc.

Meine Großmutter hingegen (Jahrgang 1922, Ruhrgebiet, plattdeutsche Wurzeln) hat jegliche Würze als "scharf" bezeichnet: "Machst du dein Essen wieder so scharf?" -- wenn ich zum Salz griff. Davon ließ sie sich auch nicht abbringen.

Answer (score -2):

*Scharf* wird naheliegend als "schmerzhaft, stechend" verstanden, insoweit *scharfe Kante* die primäre Konnotation des Wortes ist. Dies wird um so deutlicher, da man sagt, *scharfe* Speisen *brennen* im Mund.

Es erscheint mir also paradox, in Bezug auf Würze irgendetwas anderes als die Stimulation des Hitzeempfindens im Mund damit zu beschreiben.

Darüber hinaus werden Säuren zumindest auch allgemein als scharf beschrieben, zumal diese wohl auch zum Schärfeempfinden beitragen können; dennoch spricht man eher von *sauer, säuerlich*, wenn die entsprechenden Geschmacksknospen der Zunge angesprochen werden. Salz brennt in der sprichwörtlichen Wunde aber wohl nur dort (vgl auch *Entzündung*).

PS: Indo Germanische Forschung rekonstruiert *suHwos "sour, **salty**"!

Comment: "Darüber hinaus werden Säuren zumindest auch allgemein als scharf beschrieben," Wirklich? Ich hab das noch nie gehört

Comment: "Vgl. übrigens Altdeutsch brand "Schwert" (dazu würde ich selbst gern mehr erfahren)." Das gehört nicht in eine Antwort, bitte stelle eine eigene Frage dazu.

Comment: @Iris ich habe es umgestellt, so dass es den Lesefluss weniger stört. Jetzt ist es nicht mehr *in* der AW sondern nur noch *am Rande*. Danke für den Hinweis

Comment: da stand gar noch schlimmeres. habe es nun doch entfernt. dafür etwas zu "salty" gefunden.